# instagram-node synchronization issue

Tags: javascript, synchronization, sails.js, instagram-api

I am trying to write a function that gets all the user that has liked your pictures with Sails.js using [instagram-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-node) but I'm having some synchronization problems.

I tried this but it's not working because the callback is called before the getLikes().
Any ideas?

```
function getAllMediaIDs(function() {
    // Send results
});

function getAllMediaIDs(callback) {

        ig.user_self_media_recent(options, function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {

            if (err) {
                // Error
            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < medias.length; i++) {
                    getLikes(medias[i].id);
                }
                callback();
            }
        });
    }

function getLikes(mediaId) {

        ig.likes(mediaId, function(err, result, remaining, limit) {

            if (err) {
                // Error
            }
            else {

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    // Store likes    
                }

            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asynchronous operation use asynchronous loop. So, instead `for()` loop use `async.each()` or `async.eachSeries()` from [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) lib

Doc: [each()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each) / [eachSeries()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachSeries)

```
const async = require('async');

getAllMediaIDs()
   .then(function(data) {
    // ur logic
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
    // handle error
   });

function getAllMediaIDs() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ig.user_self_media_recent(options, function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {

            if (err) return reject(err); //return Error

            async.eachSeries(medias, function(key, next) {
                getLikes(key.id)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        next(); // go to next key
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        return reject(err); // something went wrong so return error
                    });
            }, function(err, data) { // <-- called when all iteratee functions have finished or error occurs
                if (err) return reject(err);
                return resolve(); // everything was good
            });
        });
    });
}

function getLikes(mediaId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        ig.likes(mediaId, function(err, result, remaining, limit) {
            if (err) return reject(err); // return error

            async.each(result, function(key, next) {
                // some store logic
                // eg. arr.push(key);
                next(); // go to next key
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) return reject(err); // return error
                return resolve(); // everything was good
            });
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't a callback() missing in function getAllMediaIDs?

Comment: @LorenzoR Right. Fixed!